# Error in updating Google play Services

Tags: android, sdk, google-play-services

While updating google play services in sdk manager it shows following errors.

Downloading Google Play services, revision 28
Download interrupted: Connection to https://dl.google.com refused
Done. Nothing was installed.
Preparing to install archives
Downloading Android SDK Build-tools, revision 23.0.1
Download interrupted: Connection to https://dl.google.com refused
Downloading Google Play services, revision 28
Download interrupted: Connection to https://dl.google.com refused
Done. Nothing was installed.
Preparing to install archives
Downloading Google Play services, revision 28
Download interrupted: Connection to https://dl.google.com refused
Done. Nothing was installed.

Can anyone help.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: This normally happens when your internet is not stable. Try checking if your connection is flaky.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply i got it after refreshing so many times

Comment: Happy to hear it worked out. Will post this as answer to be of help to someone in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This normally happens when your internet connection is not stable.

1. Try checking if your connection is flaky.
2. Retry the download when you have a stable connection.